# Find the number of times a unique value is appeared in more than one files and the number of those files

Tags: r

I have those 3 dataframes below:

```
Name<-c("jack","jack","bob","david","mary")
n1<-data.frame(Name)

Name<-c("jack","bill","dean","mary","steven")
n2<-data.frame(Name)

Name<-c("fred","alex","mary")
n3<-data.frame(Name)
```

I would like to create a new dataframe with 3 columns.All unique names present across all 3 source files in Column 1,the number
of source files in which it's located, in Column 2, and the total number of instances of that name across all files, in Column
3.

The result should be like

```
Name Number_of_files Number_of_instances
1   jack               2                   3
2    bob               1                   1
3  david               1                   1
4   mary               3                   3
5   bill               1                   1
6   dean               1                   1
7 steven               1                   1
8   fred               1                   1
9   alex               1                   1
```

Is there an automated way to achieve all these at once?

Comment: I editted. jack is displayed 3 times in total in 2 dataframes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
bind_rows(n1, n2, n3, .id = "ID") %>%
 group_by(Name) %>%
 summarise(Number_of_files = n_distinct(ID),
           Number_of_instances = n())

  Name   Number_of_files Number_of_instances
  <chr>            <int>               <int>
1 alex                 1                   1
2 bill                 1                   1
3 bob                  1                   1
4 david                1                   1
5 dean                 1                   1
6 fred                 1                   1
7 jack                 2                   3
8 mary                 3                   3
9 steven               1                   1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is conceptually similar answer as @tmfmnk but a base R version

```
#Get names of all the objects n1, n2, n3, n4 . etc
name_df <- ls(pattern = "n\\d+")

#Combine them in one dataframe
all_df <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, mget(name_df), id = name_df))

#get aggregated values
aggregate(id~Name, all_df, function(x) c(length(unique(x)), length(x)))

#    Name id.1 id.2
#1    bob    1    1
#2  david    1    1
#3   jack    2    3
#4   mary    3    3
#5   bill    1    1
#6   dean    1    1
#7 steven    1    1
#8   alex    1    1
#9   fred    1    1
```

You can rename the columns if needed.

---

And for completeness `data.table` version

```
library(data.table)

dt < - rbindlist(mget(name_df), idcol = "ID")
dt[,  list(Number_of_files = uniqueN(ID), Number_of_instances = .N), by = .(Name)]
```